# Best way to restrict some SSH users to publickey authentication only (disable password authentication)

Tags: ssh, mac-osx, configuration, mac

I'm running Mac OS X Server.app on Yosemite and I have SSH enabled for users with the default settings in `/etc/sshd_config` (publickey and password auth enabled by default).  **However, I need to restrict the `git` local user to have publickey access ONLY via SSH.**

Full disclosure, the Server.app enables some additional Kerberos and GSSAPI options (although I'm not 100% sure how these effect my questions below):

```
# Kerberos options
KerberosAuthentication yes
KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
GSSAPIKeyExchange no
```

`/etc/sshd_config` says the following:

```
# To disable tunneled clear text passwords both PasswordAuthentication and
# ChallengeResponseAuthentication must be set to "no".
```

However, `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` is not allowed in match statements, so I tried just disabling password authentication only:

```
Match User git
      PasswordAuthentication no
```

This does not work--I was still able to log in with username/password to git@my.server :(

However, adding `KbdInteractiveAuthentication no` seemed to work correctly:

```
Match User git
      PasswordAuthentication no
      KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
```

Now I get `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)` when trying to log in without a public key.  This seems to indicate that there are still methods besides publickey which will allow login from the `git` user (i.e. `gssapi-keyex` and `gssapi-with-mic`)

It seems like a better approach is to simply restrict the authentication method to `publickey`:

```
Match User git
    AuthenticationMethods publickey
```

This gives the response `Permission denied (publickey).

**Questions:**

1. What's the difference between `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` and
   `KbdInteractiveAuthentication`?  Why is
   `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` allowed in match statements but not
   `ChallengeResponseAuthentication`?
2. Is there any downside/security concern with the `AuthenticationMethods publickey` approach?
3. (Bonus if you can help me understand `gssapi-keyex`/`gssapi-with-mic` and how they relate to the GSSAPI/Kerberos options that were enabled)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a nice summary of the difference between `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` and `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` at
http://blog.tankywoo.com/linux/2013/09/14/ssh-passwordauthentication-vs-challengeresponseauthentication.html - summary is that ChallengeResponse often ends up just asking for password (but insists on it being supplied interactively).

`KbdInteractiveAuthentication` and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` are different things. It's just that `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` can end up just prompting for a password in simple cases.

`ChallengeResponseAuthentication` is a global setting and can't be specified within a `Match` clause - see the `sshd_config` man page for details.

Explicitly specifying `AuthenticationMethods publickey` for the `git` user should work fine and is better than than disabling the ones you don't want (as the list could change).

The `gssapi` options come into play if you're working in a `Kerberos` environment (such as an Active Directory domain).

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link.  Any idea about the 2nd part of question #1 above? Why is `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` allowed in match statements but not `ChallengeResponseAuthentication`?  Are these actually different things, or does the name just change inside a match block?

Comment: See update to answer (along with `sshd_config` man page for details)

Comment: I've awarded the bounty because I appreciate the response, but the man page and the other links you provided still don't give a good description of the differences between `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` and `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` (and why match only accepts `KbdInteractiveAuthentication`).  If you (or someone else) can edit this answer to provide more details, I would appreciate it.

Comment: The link in question doesn't address the keyword `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` at all.

Comment: From the [sshd_config](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html) manpage, `ChallengeResponseAuthentication` is a deprecated alias for `KbdInteractiveAuthentication `.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me if there is any difference, but at the very least, ChallengeResponseAuthentication seems to require KbdInteractiveAuthentication; it is automatically turned on if Challenge-Response is enabled.

I get the feeling from reading it that they came up with Challenge-Response during the SSH1 era.  It was standardized as keyboard-interactive with SSH2, but they didn't immediately change the server config file, to enable old configs to continue to work.

I found the following in the openssh-portable source (as of 20181214).

sshd.c starting at line 1685:

```
 /* challenge-response is implemented via keyboard interactive */
 if (options.challenge_response_authentication)
    options.kbd_interactive_authentication = 1;
```

sshconnect2.c starting at line 375:

```
 if (options.challenge_response_authentication)
    options.kbd_interactive_authentication = 1;
```